# Is it possible to distort an SVG circle?

Tags: javascript, svg

I want to use a circle element in SVG, as a container for a few other elements.

I then want to distort the lower half of the circle significantly, skewing it to one side. Is it possible to do this in a way that the effect would also apply to the child elements?

It would be trivial to draw a series of arcs (as a path) to create the shape that I'm after, but I assume that there is no way to make the child elements assume the same shape.

If it is relevant, I will be displaying in a browser, and then doing further manipulations via JavaScript.

Comment: See [transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform).

Comment: share your SVG code you have tried before

Comment: @Theraot  None of the examples on that page appear to alter the original item in the way I need - imagine trying to make something similar to the heart, but by directly distorting a circle.

Comment: @LibinPrasanth  I don't have ANY code at the moment, beyond a pair of RECTs inside a CIRCLE  But if I try a SKEW I can only get it to apply to the entire circle - maybe I am missing a magic attribute?

Comment: All the transformation are [affine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation). I don't think SVG is the right tool for the job. Although it should be possible to write a program that takes an SVG and outputs a new SVG that looks like the original but distorted the way you want.

Comment: @Theraot  Do you mean creating a SVG where the main shape is actually a PATH ?  Unless that shape can 'contain' other elements it wouldn't help - the later manipulation via JavaScript isn't going to work. Since this has to work in a browser, I don't think there are any tools that are better than SVG at the moment?

Comment: For what I was suggesting with SVG, the code would have to do the equivalent for every element. The main alternative for complex graphics in the web is canvas. You could use WebGL context, and you can use a fragment shader to do whatever. I don't know if that fits your definition of working. I found a project that renders SVG to Canvas (although it is for 2D context): https://github.com/canvg/canvg

Comment: I found an example of using SVG to create a texture for a WebGL context and apply effect: http://www.awwwards.org/brain-food-firstborn.pdf

Comment: If you are going the three-js route; also see: https://three-elements.hmans.co/